Back from Elevated Admin to Not Elevated
When running Batch Script with Administrator privileges, how to back to not Admin?
I tried this example:
@echo off
:Demo
CLS
fltmc >nul && (echo Admin& set $A=y)  || (echo Not Admin& set $A=)
fltmc >nul && (echo Back to Standard?) || (echo Get Admin?)
choice /m "Choose:"
if %errorlevel%==2 goto :Demo
if defined $A (goto :BackSTD) else (goto :GetAdmin)

:GetAdmin
PowerShell start -verb runas '%~0'& exit /b
goto :Demo

:BackSTD
PowerShell start '%~0'& exit /b
goto :Demo

But has not succeeded.
Is that possible?

“how to back to no Admin?” - You can’t Windows has absolutely no concept of sudo which is the closest to what you are describing

@Gantendo I will try it

@Gantendo Thanks. I've tried. also worked with no waiting 10 seconds

If you have a non-elevated window, and create a new window with admin privileges, you can make the old window wait until the new window is closed. This allows you to have multiple stages of elevated vs non-elevated, but will also mean you have multiple windows open at the same time.

-@LPChip Yes. This is an alternative option. This method is the same as opening an elevated new window, keeping the non-elevated old window, then closing the new window. But, usually I only use one window for one script.  The Upside of this method is not use a Task Scheduler

@Gantendo I'm still confused about what I should do between waiting for an answer or answering my own question. What do you think?

Okay. Thank You

But I still don't know yet how to write a task scheduler using batch with the No Triggers set. It's a part of this answer. Do you know how? https://superuser.com/questions/1839476/create-task-scheduler-with-no-triggers-set

I've googled and haven't produced any results. I can only write it manually (GUI)

Update
Sudo for Windows
Microsoft has released the application Sudo.exe which functions and works similarly to Linux's Sudo.
Currently, only available for Windows 11 Insider Preview Build 26052 or higher.
CMD: where.exe sudo.exe
C:\Windows\System32\sudo.exe

To Get Elevated:
sudo.exe <cmd.exe/ pwsh.exe/ powershell.exe>

Back to non-elevated Exit.
More options, type sudo.exe in Console.

Previously
To return from Elevated to Not Elevated completely, we can create a Task Scheduler and use it as Chainloader, but this method requires more scripts.
The simple and easy way is with a trick:
open an elevated new window, steadily keeping the non-elevated old window, then close the new window.
When the new runs, the old still opened but cannot be accessed and does not display anything.
By calling PowerShell with argument -Wait.
Thanks to anyone who has helped.
Below as an example:
@echo off
:Test
fltmc >nul && set $A=y || set $A=
if defined $A (echo I am A.D.M.I.N) else echo I am U.S.E.R
if defined $A (echo Back to User?)  else echo Get Admin?
set ans=& set /p ans=(Enter) Yes (AnyKey) Exit :
if defined ans (if defined $A (TASKKILL /F /IM cmd.exe /T) else exit /b)
if defined $A exit /b
PowerShell Start -Verb RunAs '%~0' -Wait
CLS& goto :Test


Haha. Compared to what? Bash/ Python/ else..

In Linux OS, just sudo -i, then exit.  In Android OS, su, then exit.
