Create Task Scheduler with No Triggers Set
I need to Create a Task Scheduler with parameters:

No Triggers
Available both in AC and DC

I learn SCHTASKS /? help, but haven't found what I mean.
I tried:
SCHTASKS /Create /TN "Test" /TR "%TEMP%\Test.cmd"

giving an error:
Invalid syntax. Mandatory option 'sc' is missing.

when I add /SC..., will giving Triggers set which I don't need.
I also don't know yet what command to disable conditions: start the task only if the PC is in AC
So, how can i make it in cmd?

You could try to set the scheduled start date to a date far in the future, e.g. /SD 1/1/9999
